# Почему не работает код для создания скриншотов?

Tags: python

У меня есть код для создания снимков экрана:

```
import pyautogui as pg
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

time.sleep(2)

imageSize = (169, 300, 3643, 1823)

for i in range(2):
    im = ImageGrab.grab(imageSize)
    im.save(i)
    im.close()
    pg.click(x=3620, y=1779)
```

При запуске выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
D:\DogAnatomyPhotos>py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User001\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2138, in save
    format = EXTENSION[ext]
KeyError: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    im.save('screenshot')
  File "C:\Users\User001\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2140, in save
    raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext)) from e
ValueError: unknown file extension:
```

Comment: Очевидно, метод save не может понять, в каком формате сохранять картинку, потому что вы этот самый формат не указали

Comment: Причём, в вопросе код программы один, а в ошибке явно другой. Но и там и там нет расширения у файла, это да.